# Composer returning proc_open(NUL) failed to open stream no such directory

Tags: php, exception, composer-php

I'm trying to get Composer to work but it simply doesn't want to, since no matter which command (install, require, init, diagnose, etc.) is used always wields that same ErrorException above. I did lots of researching already and didn't find any workaround that solved (or even mitigated) this issue.

So is there any blessed soul to shine a light or point out how stupid am I from missing something obvious?

Important info: Currently on Windows 10, running Ampps server with default configuration.

Answer (score 2):

This is a Windows configuration issue, with an explanation here: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/7186

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)