# Updating composer or running php

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have an app in laravel an when I try to run php artisan serve, I get:

> PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required
>   'C:..../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\pear') in
>   artisan on line 18

I already searched for a solution and I tried a lot of commands.
When I try the composer update, I get:

> Composer could not find a composer.json file in
>   C:\Users\mchia\OneDrive\Documents\laas_admin To initialize a project,
>   please create a composer.json file as described in the
>   https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section

But I see composer.json is in the directory and if I run `dir` I also see

> 08/07/2019  01:03 PM             1,976 composer.json

When I run composer diagnose, I get:

> [ErrorException] proc_open(NUL): failed to open stream: No such file
>   or directory

I have actualized windows10 yesterday maybe is that?

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48554848/composer-returning-proc-opennul-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-directory

Comment: Doesn´t work for me.

Comment: According to [this issue](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/8152), the problem is that you're project is on OneDrive.

Move your project to a local folder and try again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the project was in OneDrive. When I move from the one drive folder it works.